# configure my linux as a router, how do enable port forwarding with nftables?

Tags: linux, firewall, nat, nftables

I'm trying to configure my Gentoo Linux as a router.

this is my configuration so far.

WAN NIC is `enp3s0` and LAN NIC is `enp1s0f0`

accepting connections to ICMP, tcp ports 53, 22, 80, 443, 445, 5900 and udp ports 53,67,68 from LAN

accepting connection from SSH port 22 from WAN

these work great, what I failed to do is create port forwarding.

I am trying to set up that if a connection on port 222 comes in from WAN, to forward it to machine with ip address `192.168.1.2` on port `22` and this rule doesn't produce an error, but also doesn't allow me to connect.

this is my configuration:

```
table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related } accept
        iif "lo" accept
        iif "enp1s0f0" tcp dport { 22, 53, 80, 443, 445, 5900 } counter packets 0 bytes 0 log accept
        iif "enp3s0" tcp dport { 22 } counter packets 0 bytes 0 log accept
        iif "enp1s0f0" udp dport { 53, 67, 68 } accept
        iif "enp1s0f0" ip protocol icmp accept
        counter packets 1 bytes 259 drop
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        ct state { established, related, new } accept
        iif "lo" accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        iif "enp3s0" oif "enp1s0f0" ct state { established, related } accept
        iif "enp1s0f0" oif "enp3s0" accept
        iif "enp3s0" oif "enp1s0f0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname "enp3s0" masquerade
    }

    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority 100; policy accept;
        iif "enp3s0" tcp dport { 222 } dnat to 192.168.1.2:22  ### <- PORT FORWARDING RULE HERE
    }
}
```

how can I correct this problem?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the first packet of a new flow (thus state NEW) traverses the *nat prerouting* chain, *dnat* happens and with the new destination the packet is routed and traverses the *filter forward* chain.

Then this rule drops it:

> ```
>         iif "enp3s0" oif "enp1s0f0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
> ```

---

A rule to allow this first packet (which is not in *established* state) is needed.

This could be inserted before the drop rule in a first naive way:

```
iif "enp3s0" oif "enp1s0f0" ip daddr 192.168.1.2 tcp dport 22 accept
```

and because of the specific topology: the 192.168.1.0/24 LAN isn't routable so is not reachable by default from Internet, it would probably be good enough (technically the next hop router could cheat and reach 192.168.1.2:22 directly without NAT). But if the system wasn't doing any *masquerade* (and there was a routable LAN instead of 192.168.1.0/24) this would leave the service reachable directly.

There's actually a simpler and safer method which is also more generic in case some other ports are also *dnat*-ed and all such *dnat* rules are all to be allowed: add a rule that allows *any* packet that underwent a [*dnat* transformation](https://manpages.debian.org/nft.8#CONNTRACK_TYPES). It's more detailed in the equivalent *iptables-extensions*' [conntrack match](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#conntrack):

> DNAT
>
> A virtual state, matching if the original destination differs from the
> reply source.

Just insert this instead in *filter forward* before the last *drop* rule:

```
ct status dnat accept
```

or to be a bit more precise:

```
iif enp3s0 oif enp1s0f0 ct status dnat accept
```

up to very precise:

```
iif enp3s0 oif enp1s0f0 ct state new ct status dnat ip daddr 192.168.1.2 tcp dport 22 accept
```

This status can only appear because of a previous *dnat* rule done on a flow, so it validates the intent: accept.

---

Notes:

- there is no need to use different tables for different hook types (*filter* and *nat*) as long as it's about the same family (*ip* here).

  That's an habit inherited from *iptables* that might limit possibilities. For example, the scope of a [*set*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Named_sets) is a table. Using the same set between a *filter* chain and a *nat* chain requires them to be in the same table (where the *set* is defined). Sadly many examples even from the wiki still use naming conventions mimicing *iptables*.
- while it doesn't matter here, the historical priority for *nat prerouting* isn't 100 but -100 (aka *dstnat*).

  It would only matter if there were other tables also including *nat prerouting* chains or if *iptables* *nat* rules were used together (and in such case it would be advised to use -101 or -99 rather than exactly -100), to determine which rules take precedence.